# is this good idea to put every part of my page as a partial view in asp mvc5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, page-layout

is this a good idea to separate all of these parts to different partial views, I want to make my cshtml file to be very small and easy to manage!!!

my web page different parts

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of application you are trying to develop. If it is a single page application, then it sould be in partial views.

In another scenario is to load a component separately which if loaded directly would cause the page load time to increase.